# How to run JQuery code and external libraries in ionic (Angular JS) for my hybrid app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to create an app in ionic for my existing site and trying to add all JQuery code and use external libraries like Lightbox, Slider, etc within my app.

I was hoping if you guys could tell me (may be with an example) that is it a different way to run JQuery code when the app is ready or am I missing something.

Here are few ways I tried, but it doesn't work through code. (These both work when I test them through Console).

```
angular.element('.myclass').addClass('className');
```

and

```
$('.myclass').addClass('className');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery inside a Angular app is always a bad practice.
Your code probably don't work because at the load event the Angular app is still loading and rendering the page.
So basically when jquery gets executed your page is still empty or not completely rendered.
That's probably why if you run it through the console it works normally, because the page is correctly rendered.

Comment: Understood, is there any then to run my external libraries in it?

Comment: You have to use angular libraries, that's the easiest way.

Comment: The problem is that I am pulling ready HTML pages through REST and hence I'd have to write JQuery to support all the animation. I'll be grateful if you could tell me a way even if it's a bad practice